# How do I get items in Team Fortress 2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I picked up the Orange Box, mostly to play Portal, but I've played TF2 a bit here and there. In all my playing, I've never seen an item drop.

Am I just not looking properly? Do I have to run up and loot the corpse à la *World of Warcraft*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [item drop system](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Item_drop_system) gives you a random item after a certain amount of time.

> Players are guaranteed to find items at regular intervals of 30 to 70 minutes, with an average interval of 50 minutes.
>
> There is no cap on the amount of items that can be received per week, but instead a cap on the amount of playtime in which drops can occur

Each class also has items that are awarded based on completing [achievements](http://tf2wiki.net/wiki/Achievement_weapons) with that class in addition to being randomly found.

Comment: You'll also get a notification after your next death that you received an item and it will bring up a large picture and description of it.

Comment: Do the winter items work the same way?

Comment: @McKay: If you mean the items for the achievement, no.  Those drop as actual presents from dead players, and you need to collect 3 of them for the achievement.

Comment: Also, there's a weekly limit on the number of items you can get.

Comment: @Ullallulloo - According to the official wiki "There is no cap on the amount of items that can be received per week, but instead a cap on the amount of playtime in which drops can occur."

Comment: @OrigamiRobot: That does still limit it to 6 to 12 items a week, and either way, it's still worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

items drop in randomly, but earning achievements help you collect items. pick items wisely. for example, if you want to headshot people, choose the sniper rifle over the huntsman(bow and arrow) because of the aim of sniper.The huntsman would be better for attack.